# Show and dismiss View Cntrollers in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a view controller and dismiss my current modal view. I saw the answers on StackOverflow, but I don't understand it.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController")
        self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Could anyone please tell me, how to do it simply? Thanks

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457278/how-to-present-and-dismiss-at-same-time/48457581#48457581

Comment: which one is correct there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your main controller in stack and pop all other view controllers and then present new View Controller.

```
if let controllers =  self.navigationController?.viewControllers  {
    for vc in controllers {
        // Check if the view controller is of MainViewController type
        if let myVC = vc as? MainViewController {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(myVC, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Push view controller :

```
let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

or Present View Controller :

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondViewController
self.present(next as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to Present viewcontroller.

```
let yourVC = UIStoryboard(name: storyBord, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:ID) as! yourViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourVC)
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: { 

    })
```

And for dissmissing use this in your presented viewController

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

            })
```

Comment: ? is dismiss the current modalview and present the new VC

Comment: I use the above code it presented the next view controller but previous view controller stills open

Comment: @V_rohit So your requirement is to dismiss the current viewcontroller which is presented over another viewController say viewControllerA and then present another viewController from viewControllerA ?

Comment: I have a main view controller in which I want to show and dismiss the various view controllers